# Facebook App connects to website from desktop but not from mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile

I have a simple app that just accesses my website. From my FB Business Page it works fine clicking/tapping the "Use App" button displayed in the cover image using both desktop and mobile. It also works fine from the "Apps" section in the left sidebar on desktop. If I search FB, I can find both my page and my app in the search results. I can see the icon for my app in the search results. From desktop I can click the app icon returned from search, and it works fine. On mobile if I tap the app icon, the error "The page you requested was not found" is displayed.

How can I get my app to work on mobile too?

Comment: same problem with me, did you find the solution?